# How to move half an element to the background

Tags: html, css, frontend, z-index

I’m making a website on bootstrap and it is necessary that one part of the element is visible and the other part is hidden behind the other element as in the [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nkoyO.png), how can I do this?

```
HTML 
<section class="about">
        <img src="img/about-el-img.png" class="about-el-img">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row align-items-center">
                <div class="col-xl-5 offset-xl-1">
                    <h2 class="about-title">Сервис обмена электронных
                    валют с 5-летней историей</h2>
                    <p class="about-desc">За время работы мы приобрели репутацию проверенного партнера и 
                    делаем все возможное, чтобы ваши впечатления от нашего сервиса были только 
                    благоприятными.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xl-6">
                    <img src="img/about-img.png" class="about-img" alt="Картинка">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</section>

CSS
.about
    position: relative
    .about-el-img
        position: absolute
        top: 0
        left: 220px
    .container
        border: 4px solid #F7F8FD
        border-radius: 26px
        padding-bottom: 88px
    &-img
        max-width: 100%
    &-title
        font-weight: 500
        font-size: 35px
        line-height: 132.4%
        color: #160647
        padding: 102px 0 30px
        max-width: 320px
    &-desc
        font-size: 18px
        line-height: 166.5%
        opacity: 0.7
        color: $main-text
        max-width: 400px
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of z-index to do this :

```
.about{
      position:relative
   }
.about-el-img{ 
       position:absolute
   }
.container{
       position:absolute
       z-index:1
   }
```

If you want to show the image in above and container below, then use z-index:1 in .about-el-image. This concept in known as stacking in CSS.